# Concat with if else in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named phone , which contains 3 columns

```
  ======================
  | TEL1 | TEL2  | TEL3 |
  =======================
  | 123  | 455   | 3434 |
  =======================
  |      | 455   | 3434 |
  =======================
  | 675  |       |      |
  =======================
  | 123  |       |      |
  =======================
  | 123  | 455   | 3434 |
```

I want to concatenate these columns into  one column 1 using mysql query which results like below table

```
 +---------------------+
 |   Telephone         |
 +---------------------+
 |   123/455/3435      |
 +---------------------+
 |   455/3435          |
 +---------------------+
 |    675              |
 +---------------------+
 |   123               |
 +---------------------+
 |   123/455/3435      |
 +---------------------+
```

Not the result like below which I am getting using CONCAT_WS('/',`TEL1`, `TEL2`, `TEL3`) function

```
 +---------------------+
 |   Telephone         |
 +---------------------+
 |   123/455/3435      |
 +---------------------+
 |   455/3435          |
 +---------------------+
 |    675//            |
 +---------------------+
 |   123//             |
 +---------------------+
 |   123/455/3435      |
 +---------------------+
```

Please Help me write the query for above kind of result

Comment: @shree.pat18 too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT_WS('/', TEL1 , TEL1 , TEL1 ),'//','') Telephone
FROM   `table`;
```

**EDIT**

you can use **replace** function like above

Take a look at **[HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)**

Comment: I am getting the same result as i have explained in above comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**CONCAT_WS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('/',`TEL1`, `TEL2`, `TEL3`) 
FROM Table1
```

Comment: what i m getting in result for third row is 675// and fourth row is 123// but i want only 675 and 123 not "//" if some column does not contain values?